# Airplane mode turns on when I turn off Wi-Fi

Tags: bluetooth, airplane-mode

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. Whenever I turn OFF Wi-Fi (Bluetooth being off), Airplane Mode turns ON automatically. If I turn OFF Airplane Mode, it automatically turns Bluetooth ON (even though Bluetooth was OFF earlier).

Any ideas what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: To me auto-activation of flight mode after turning off Bluetooth and Wi-Fi sounds reasonable. But it shouldn't turn on Bluetooth after disabling flight mode. That sounds like a bug.

Comment: Not a bug if it does the same with other OS and that is exactly what happens with most laptops.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an extension which allows you to prevents this behavior. It's called "Sane Airplane Mode" and you can get it from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/AntiKippi/gnome-shell-extension-sane-airplane-mode).