# How can I disable Bluetooth automatically everytime I turn OFF Airplane Mode?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, airplane-mode

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I never use the Bluetooth so I always turn it off. That means: if I disable wifi the device goes into Airplane Mode. I get that it makes sense to turn on Airplane Mode when wifi and Bluetooth are off.
The problem is: When I want to turn my wifi on again, I have to disable the Airplane Mode and that results in automatically turning on the Bluetooth again. That means that I have to disable the Bluetooth manually every time, even though it was turned off before.

I know of these two posts (and there are more):

[Airplane mode turns on when I turn off Wi-Fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960223/airplane-mode-turns-on-when-i-turn-off-wi-fi)

[Airplane mode automatic turn on problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074992/airplane-mode-automatic-turn-on-problem)

I also know that there is a bug report
[here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1767542).

However, my question remains: Is there a script I can write or some airplane mode configurations I can tweak right now **so that I don't have to turn off Bluetooth manually every time I exit the Airplane Mode**? I am new to scripting/editing configs and don't want to break stuff.

Edit:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:568b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31, is that what you meant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deactivate internal bluetooth adapter while leaving usb dongle online](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898881/deactivate-internal-bluetooth-adapter-while-leaving-usb-dongle-online) just replace 105b with 0cf3 and replace e065 with e300 so the entry is `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0cf3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="e300", ATTR{authorized}="0"`

Comment: HI, I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: depending on the hw, one may disable bluetooth in bios (via a simple checkbox), which may meet your requirements. (i'm actually re/searching the opposite: a way to *enable* bluetooth (by default), as mine keeps getting disabled when rebooting.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a GNOME extension called "Sane Airplane Mode" which does exactly that. You can install it from the [GNOME Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4604/sane-airplane-mode/) website or from [Github](https://github.com/AntiKippi/gnome-shell-extension-sane-airplane-mode).